# rspec test that uses dummy data from an entire table in rails app database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I want to write an rspec test that uses `MyModel.all` (i.e. all the records for a model) and does some things with it and returns a result

Is it possible to generate a new database table (i.e model) from within rspec? And then destroy it at the end of the test? Is this considered good practice (theoretically, if a dev working on the project coincidentally made a table of the same name and it could get dropped by the test). Or is this considered so unlikely it's okay to generate a randomly named table in a test?

Note: the test *must* extract all the records in the model, hence why it would be nice to simply generate one (a very small one) inside the test, rather than use an actual table, which may be large and slow down tests unnecessarily

The method I am trying to test is along the lines of

```rb
def my_method(model_name)
  the_table = eval(model_name).all

  # does some things

end
```

The key feature of the method is that it accepts the model name (and retrieves all the records for the model *inside* the method)

The test is along the lines of

```rb
it "ensures something" do

  # tests

  expect(result).to eq(true)

end
```

Comment: Tests are normally isolated, so you seed a test database with controlled fixtures. It's commonly bad practice to use dynamic / live data. Also, it has no use to test models that do not exist in your real application, why would you otherwise test it? Have you checked FactoryBot gem? It's quite easy to use in seeding data for tests,

Comment: @bo-oz I will check out FactoryBot. Basically I have a method that takes an entire table as an input. So the only way to test it (I think) is to give it what it needs (an entire table). The table definitely doesn't have to be an exact one being used in the app - it can be a small table with just a few records and perhaps 5 columns

Comment: Read the RSpec documentation on mocking and stubbing. Without seeing the code you are trying test it's hard to say what you need to do, but we can often use standin objects to represent parts of the code that will be called during execution but who's functionality we aren't interested in testing in a given test. For example we don't want to test the MyModel.all as it's a library method and we assume it works as advertised.

Comment: @PaulByrne that sounds like a good approach, except the method actually accepts the name of a model (e.g. `"Mymodel"`) and inside the method `eval(model).all` is called to retrieve the table

Comment: That doesn't matter. Mocking objects is about stand-ins that respond to certain messages with specified responses. Why don't you post the code you have.

Comment: @PaulByrne done

Comment: eval(model_name).all won't return 'the table', it will return all records for the given model. You will already have a test database that cleans itself on each run, so you can simply create a couple of records before the test in a before block, and when you call the method above in your test, you'll have the records. A mocking approach is not necessary at all here.

Comment: @PaulByrne I included a test, could you show it with a before block?

Comment: Just call MyModel.create in a before block with whatever attributes you need. The examples in the documentation are very clear. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks As the above poster said you can simply record creation using FctoryBot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an uncomplicated solution

Rails automatically creates a test db with the same schema as dev/prod. So all you need to do is add some data before you run your test

e.g.

```rb
# Add some records 
@model_name = Model_name.new(name: "John", email: "john@gmail.com")
@model_name.save

# run your test
it "ensures something" do

  # tests

  expect(result).to eq(true)

end
```

Also note:

- Your rspec tests will use the test database, which is exactly the same structure as your development database, but just that it will start empty (hence why you have to add some data to it)
- You can very easily put data in your test database in the same way that you would with your development (or production) databases
- Note that anything you do to the test database in your `spec.rb` file will be rolled back after the tests complete